# Why do I get fatal nil error when assigning a custom UIControl to a member variable without first assigning it to a local variable?

Tags: ios, swift, null, uicontrol

I have a custom control in a UIToolbar.  The Toolbar is subclassed and it holds the control as a member variable.

```
var segmentCtl:VGSegment!
```

When the toolbar initializes it creates the control as follows:

```
let categoryCtl = VGSegment(frame: placeholder.frame, segmentConfiguration: config, titles: titles)

categoryCtl.delegate = delegate

let tbButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: categoryCtl)
items?.remove(at: 0)
items?.insert(tbButton, at: 0)
```

This all works fine and exits with the variable categoryCtl having a valid value.  Sometime later when the variable is accessed, I get the fatal nil error.

I'm able to correct this by using a local variable for the control creation and then assigning it the member variable.  Code is as follows:

```
let segment = VGSegment(frame: placeholder.frame, segmentConfiguration: config, titles: titles)

segment.delegate = delegate

categoryCtl = segment

let tbButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: segment)
items?.remove(at: 0)
items?.insert(tbButton, at: 0)
```

It appears that the garbage collector sees it as unreferenced and frees it. While it is fixed, I'd like a better understanding of the underlying swift and framework behaviors that result in this. I'd appreciate anyone's expertise on this area.

[image: Screen Shot in xcode]

Comment: You're creating a local variable in both cases.  In the first one you never assign the local one to the property so the property is nil.

Comment: remove "let" in front of "segment" in both cases

Comment: This is why I strongly suggest you get into the habit of using `self.` when you are referring to a property even though it is often optional to do so in Swift

Comment: @dan Good observation. That was a mistake I made when I reproduced the code for this post.  I corrected it by taking the let off and I get the same nil problem immediately after the declaration when it assigns the delegate.  Using self.categoryCtl for all the assignments and reads also results in the nil fatal error?